# Wrapping a RESTapi with GraphQL using Apollo React

Tags: javascript, rest, graphql, react-apollo

I need to do a project (currency exchange app) using Apollo client and React. I need to wrap an existing REST api (fixer.io) with graphql. So far no luck finding a solution online. Tried several tutorials but they don't seem to work. Anyone have experience with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use [Apollo client 2.0](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) and want everything to be client side.

First you need an [apollo bridge link](https://github.com/dacz/apollo-bridge-link). It's used "When you don't have GraphQL server (yet) and want to use GraphQL on the client". Its source code is quite short, so you can inline it:

```
/*
  Copyright (c) 2017 David Cizek
  https://github.com/dacz/apollo-bridge-link
*/
import { GraphQLSchema, graphql, print } from 'graphql';
import { addMockFunctionsToSchema, makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import Observable from 'zen-observable';

export const createBridgeLink = ({ schema, resolvers, mock, context = {} }) => {
    let executableSchema;
    if (typeof schema === 'string') {
        executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: schema, resolvers });
    } else if (schema.kind === 'Document') {
        executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
            typeDefs: print(schema),
            resolvers,
        });
    } else if (schema instanceof GraphQLSchema) {
        executableSchema = schema;
    } else {
        throw new Error('schema should be plain text, parsed schema or executable schema.');
    }

    if (mock)
        {addMockFunctionsToSchema({
            schema: executableSchema,
            preserveResolvers: true,
        });}

    return new ApolloLink(
        operation =>
            new Observable(observer => {
                const { headers, credentials } = operation.getContext();
                const ctx = {
                    ...context,
                    headers,
                    credentials,
                };

                graphql(executableSchema, print(operation.query), undefined, ctx, operation.variables, operation.operationName)
                    .then(data => {
                        observer.next(data);
                        observer.complete();
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        /* istanbul ignore next */
                        observer.error(err);
                    });
            }),
    );
};

export class BridgeLink extends ApolloLink {
    requester;

    constructor(opts) {
        super();
        this.requester = createBridgeLink(opts).request;
    }

    request(op) {
        return this.requester(op);
    }
}
```

Next you create schema and resolvers:

```
// schema.js
export default `
type Rate {
  date: Date!
  rate: Float!
}

type Query {
  latestRate(from: String!, to: String!): Rate
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
`;


// resolvers.js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    latestRate(obj, args, context, info) {
      return fetch(`https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=${args.from}`).then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => { date: res.date, rate: res.rates[args.to] })
    }
  }
}

export default resolvers;
```

Finally, you create an apollo client factory:

```
// clientFactory.js
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

import { BridgeLink } from './apollo-bridge-link';

import schema from './schema';
import resolvers from './resolvers';

export default () => {
    const mock = false;
    const context = {};

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        link: new BridgeLink({ schema, resolvers, mock, context }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
    return client;
};
```

Here's how you use it:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import clientFactory from './clientFactory'

const client = clientFactory();

client.query(gql`query {
  latestRate(from: "USD", to: "EUR") { date, rate }
}`).then(console.log)
```

If you want to use it in React:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
const client = clientFactory();

const App = ({ data: { latestRate, refetch } }) => {
  return <div>
    <span>Today:</span><span>{latestRate.date}</span>
    <span>1 USD equals:</span><span>{latestRate.rate} EUR</span>
    <button onClick={() => refetch()}>
      Refresh
    </button>
  </div>
}

const AppWithQuery = graphql(gql`
  query {
    latestRate(from: "USD", to: "EUR") { date, rate }
  }
`)(App);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <AppWithQuery/>
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

With the [Graphcool Framework](https://www.graph.cool/forum/t/feedback-framework-preview/949), you can define [*resolver functions*](https://blog.graph.cool/extend-your-graphcool-api-with-resolvers-ca0f0270bca7), which allow you to easily wrap any REST API. You can define a function and connect it to a specific mutation or query in your GraphQL Schema.

I prepared [a demo, wrapping the fixer API](https://graphqlbin.com/RoQhG).

Try to run this query to get the exchange rates with USD as base, for example:

```
query {
  fixer(
    base: "USD"
  ) {
    base
    date
    eur
    usd
    rub
  }
}
```

You can build this demo yourself like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:graphcool/templates.git
cd templates/curated/misc/fixer-wrapper
npm install -g graphcool@next
graphcool init
graphcool deploy
graphcool playground
```

Please feel free to share any improvement you might have in mind, the example is [open source](https://github.com/graphcool/templates). You can read more about resolvers [here](https://docs-next.graph.cool/reference/functions/resolvers-su6wu3yoo2).

Comment: you can also refer to this example: https://github.com/graphcool/graphcool/tree/master/examples/rest-wrapper